# Filamentphp Spatie Media Library 'SpatieMediaLibraryImageColumn' relationship incompatible

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-filament

When I am trying to use   SpatieMediaLibraryImageColumn in the Filament Table  I get the following error which I'm unable to resolve.

> Declaration of Filament\Tables\Columns\SpatieMediaLibraryImageColumn::applyEagerLoading(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation $query): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation must be compatible with Filament\Tables\Columns\Column::applyEagerLoading(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder

```php
public static function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
            ->columns([
                TextColumn::make('journals_id'),
                TextColumn::make('manuscript_type_id'),
                TextColumn::make('submission_id'),
                TextColumn::make('reference_id'),
                TextColumn::make('edm_reference_id'),
                TextColumn::make('doi'),
                TextColumn::make('title'),

                SpatieMediaLibraryImageColumn::make('manuscripts'),

                TextColumn::make('sub_title'),
                TextColumn::make('created_at')->date()->since(),
                TextColumn::make('updated_at')->date()->since(),
            ])
            ->filters([
                //
            ])
            ->actions([
                Tables\Actions\EditAction::make(),
            ])
            ->bulkActions([
                Tables\Actions\DeleteBulkAction::make(),
            ]);
    }
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;
use Spatie\Image\Manipulations;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaCollections\Models\Media;

class Manuscript extends Model implements HasMedia
{
    use HasFactory, InteractsWithMedia;

    protected $fillable=[
      'journal_id','submission_id','manuscript_type_id',
      'reference_id','edm_reference_id','doi','title','sub_title'
    ];

    public function registerMediaConversions(Media $media = null): void
    {
        $this
            ->addMediaConversion('preview')
            ->fit(Manipulations::FIT_CROP, 300, 300)
            ->nonQueued();
    }
}
```

Comment: Had the same issue. I ran a `composer update` and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

As @mrks_diehl suggested, running

```php
composer update
```

Solves the problem.